# filter out duplicates from text file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file as follows:

```
a b 1.25 3.5
a c 1.25 3.4
b c 3.4  3.5
d e 3.4  3.4
f g 4.5  6.7
a b 1.3  4.6
```

I would like to remove the rows which have duplicate entries based on the first column or second columns values. All the posts I have seen so far retain the first instance of the duplicate.  The output should look something like

```
d e 3.4  3.4
f g 4.5  6.7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{cnt1[$1]++; cnt2[$2]++; next} (cnt1[$1]==1) && (cnt2[$2]==1)' file file
d e 3.4  3.4
f g 4.5  6.7
```

Comment: more succinctly `cnt1[$1]*cnt2[$2]==1`

Comment: Hmmmm - I'd have to say more briefly rather than succinctly as I think that's quite a bit less clear.

Comment: @EdMorton - Hmmmm -- Who was it who used the formula: "IMHO it more obfuscates the code for those of us used to the [...] approach"? :-)

Comment: @peak are you suggesting there's some common idiom of using `a*b==1` instead of `a==1 && b==1`?

Comment: I read it very similar to `a^2==1` instead of `a==1 || a==-1`

Comment: It's not, though, because 2*0.5==1 is not the same as 2==1 && 0.5==1 and -1*-1==1 is not the same as -1==1 && -1==1. Of course I understand that in this case the counts can't be fractions or negatives but I'm just not buying that it's a good idea to write `a*b==1` vs spelling out what you really mean with `a==1 && b==1`. YMMV I suppose.